# Can we setAttribute on Alert?

Tags: javascript, alert, dom-events, tizen

I have created an alert on Samsung Tv App that shows some warning now I want to apply Text to speech on alert but it only reads `OK Button` not the alert message instead I want to read the alert message than `OK button`.

So to do that I have to `setAttribute('role', 'alert')` but I don't know how can I do that

Comment: @Badasskid i am using samsungtv built it api here is link https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/guides/fundamentals/text-to-speech.html  you can get some info from here

Comment: Not clear what you are looking for

Comment: is there any way i can set Attribute property on alert @manikantgautam

Answer (score 1):

You can set that attribute directly on markup if it's in access control.